Excel VBA to modify plot chart's point label work fine on local drive but not on onedrive
I created a vba code to modify the chart's label data font. Everything works fine when I used it locally. But when I uploaded the file to onedrive for my colleagues to use it, the macro didn't work properly.
The code is like so:
With .Points(itc).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
 .name = pltatt.LabelFont
 .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = pltatt.LabelColor
 .Bold = pltatt.LabelStyleBold
 .Italic = pltatt.LabelStyleItalic
 .size = pltatt.LabelSize
End With

Everything is fine but size changing part doesn't work.
If I delete all the other, then it works again.
I don't really know why, anyone has any ideas?
P/S: pltatt is a class modules that I created, I already tried to use constant values but it didn't work either.
If the other users download the file to other places than open in desktop app, it works. But not when they open it online in web browser or in desktop mode.

VBA is not executed in web browser, so nothing will happen. When opening in desktop mode, probably macros are disabled by default - so likely the code would work, but is not triggered at all.

Thank you @FunThomas for the answer. Sorry for not mentioned it properly. The macro in my file is enabled, I can do pretty much all the other macros in my file. This specific line " .size = pltatt.LabelSize" does not work when  " .name = pltatt.LabelFont,  .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = pltatt.LabelColor, .Bold = pltatt.LabelStyleBold,  .Italic = pltatt.LabelStyleItalic" are around. If I delete those lines, It works again.

So if macros are enabled and the routine is triggered, you should use the debugger to see what is going on. Are the values in pltatt filled correctly? Are the other properties like font name and color set? Is an error happening but not displayed as you are using On Error... to suppress errors?

What if you set the size before the other settings?

Thank you both for your answers. But it still does not work.
To FunThomas: I watched the values, and it's all filled. The others are set, only size does not work. And I don't use any error handling here.
To JonPeltier: thank you for your suggestion. When I set the size first, it actually work the first time, but then Italic part does not work. I try to randomly reorder the properties but always there's one not work, and order is also random, the second, the third etc may not work . If I copy that file to C driver or anywhere else, it works again.  Maybe onedrive path is the problem.
